# iPad fails to appear in Finder over Wi-Fi

Tags: wifi, catalina

I just updated my MacBook Pro (2018, 15") to macOS Catalina (10.15), and my 11" iPad Pro to iPadOS (13.1.2).

Since then, I haven't been able to connect the iPad to the Mac in the Finder over Wi-Fi, although my iPhone works fine. (This means that iOS devices are shown in the Sidebar.) The Mac and the iPad are both connected to the same network, too.

So, for instance, I can't sync the iPad in Music and Sidecar doesn't work as the iPad just doesn't show up in the window. Both of these things work over USB.

Does anybody have insight as to what might be going on? Thanks!

Comment: I have the same exact problem, but not just my iPad that doesn't show anymore, my iPhone 7 Plus and XS are gone too!

Comment: After a while, the iPad showed up in Finder after all. I still don't know why it happened at first.

Answer (score 2):

Relaunch the Finder. For that Option-click on the Finder icon in the Dock, then click Relaunch.

Comment: Assuming that has the same effect that the `killall Finder` command in the Terminal followed by the automatic relaunch does, that didn't help. Unfortunately, in the course of normal updates and so on my problem went away "on its own", so I can't test solutions anymore. For that reason I'll flag the question for closure. Thank you for your help anyway!